# What clustering method can deal with multi-dimensional data?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am very confused about that, and I am a newcomer to clustering.

Recently, I made a csv file and its data structure as below:
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN6j3.png)

As you see, the value in every element is array and there are two array shape:[1,2] and [2,1]. In short, I have 200 samples and everyone have 400 features, but the type of every feature is array.

So, is Kmeans can handle it or is there other method can cluster this type of data? Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That being said, I'd go for a technique like subspace clustering or projected clustering.

Comment: Probably want to take a look at [T-SNE](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't flat this data out?

Comment: Is there any way you can share the csv? @杨键刚 Using a link perhaps

Comment: Because data in every element is correlative, if I flat this data, it means data become independent. In this case, clustering may become meaningless, so I want to thank every element as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

K-means computes means. The canonical definition of means on arrays - component wise - is equivalent to flattening your data in a n*p array shape.

Other methods such as HAC and DBSCAN *can* be used with any data where you have a distance function, e.g., polygons.

Which leads to the main problem: you can't "just" cluster. You need to identify the right way of handling your data. If minimizing squared deviations from a component wise mean is what you want, then k-means. If you have a way to quantify distance, then HAC and DBSCAN. Otherwise, you will *first* need to figure out how to measure similarity in a way that is helpful for your use case.